# regex - find subsequent lines after a match. Work with pythex but not in script (with python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got the following text

```
Title: The Divine Comedy, Complete
        The Vision of Paradise, Purgatory and Hell
```

I'm using this regex to get hold of the subsequent lines

```
(?<=Title:)[.|\n|\W|\w]*
```

It works well within regex online builder like this one `https://pythex.org/`

However, I'm creating a regex object like below

```
 re.compile(r'(?<=Title:)[.|\n|\W|\w]*', re.IGNORECASE)
```

And when I run it, I've got

```
File "./script1_c.py", line 33, in <module>
title = re.search(title_search, doc).group('title')
IndexError: no such group
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I change the `IGNORECASE` to a `MULTILINE`? TIA

Comment: You don't have any named groups - it matches, but there's nothing specified to extract. Try `r'(?<=Title:)(?P<title>[.|\n|\W|\w]*)'` (see [here](http://regex101.com/r/gB5qQ4/1)).

Comment: That works fine , Jon. Thanks ! Why don't you put it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have no groups in your pattern, named or otherwise, so the only group you can return is `0`, i.e. the entire match.

Address this by either using numeric groups:

```
title_search = re.compile(r'(?<=Title:)([.\n\W\w]*)', re.IGNORECASE) 
title = re.search(title_search, data).group(1)
```

Or named groups:

```
title_search = re.compile(r'(?<=Title:)(?P<title>[.\n\W\w]*)', re.IGNORECASE) 
title = re.search(title_search, data).group('title')
```

Note, you don't need the `|` symbols in your character set. The pipe symbol is used to indicate a choice between two patterns, but only outside character sets.

Finally, you could use `re.DOTALL` to simplify your pattern:

```
title_search = re.compile(r'(?<=Title:)(?P<title>.*)',re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```